# Query to "PIVOT" the results of SalesAmount & CumulativeMonthly for specific YEARS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a database table that captures every Sales Transaction:

```
Transactions 
(
    ID INT, 
    TransactionDate DATETIME, 
    SalesAmount MONEY
)
```

I need to run a T-SQL query to produce a Sales Report, that shows :

(1) Sales (monthly)
 (2) Cumulative Monthly Sales

These will be two columns per year; PIVOT the results for next year on next two neighbor columns (structure as ExcelSheet template below). The results will extend horizontally for all Years in the transaction data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggegation and window functions, as follows:

```
select
    datename(month, TransactionDate),
    sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2017 then SalesAmount end) [Sales 2017],
    sum(sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2017 then SalesAmount end))
        over(order by month(TransactionDate)) [Cumulative 2017],
    sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2018 then SalesAmount end) [Sales 2018],
    sum(sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2018 then SalesAmount end))
        over(order by month(TransactionDate)) [Cumulative 2018],    
    sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2019 then SalesAmount end) [Sales 2019],
    sum(sum(case when year(TransactionDate) = 2019 then SalesAmount end))
        over(order by month(TransactionDate)) [Cumulative 2019],        
from Transactions
group by month(TransactionDate), datename(month, TransactionDate)
order by month(TransactionDate)
```